# What's the difference between HttpResponseException and HttpException

Tags: asp.net-mvc

From http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling

> HttpResponseException
>
> What happens if a Web API controller throws an exception? By default,
>   most exceptions are translated into an HTTP response with status code
>   500, Internal Server Error.
>
> The HttpResponseException type is a special case. This exception
>   returns any HTTP status code that you specify in the constructor of
>   the exception.

Except that it **doesn't**. Fiddler shows me a 500 is returned.

However, HttpException seems to do what that article says.

Is the documentation wrong or am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

While typing that out, I had an idea. I tried both from two controllers, an ApiController and a standard MVC controller.

The two exception work in reverse to each other depending on the type of controller they're thrown from.

- Use HttpResponseException to return a proper HTTP code from an API
  controller.
- Use HttpException to return a proper HTTP code from an
  MVC controller.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Moved my update to an answer]

While typing that out, I had an idea. I tried both from two controllers, an ApiController and a standard MVC controller.

The two exception work in reverse to each other depending on the type of controller they're thrown from.

- Use HttpResponseException to return a proper HTTP code from an API controller.
- Use HttpException to return a proper HTTP code from an MVC controller.

Comment: Thx, this explains why my framework used to work perfectly fine with MVC Controllers (returning the correct exception) and doesn't with API Controllers anymore (returning 500) - but it just doesn't make any sense :(